# How to Import JavaScript from external file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created Simple HTML page and I have imported JavaScript within  tag. 
It works fine (When click div s make visible and hide)

I want to import JavaScript from external file and I made changes as below. Then hidden div s are always visible cannot hide and make visible manually

What is the wrong with fallowing code

**Working code (when Java Script in 'head' tag)**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://hp-parts.orgfree.com/hpcss.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
$('.box').hide();

// Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
// with a click event to toggle the "box" state
$('.clickme').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
})

</script>
</head>

<body align="center">
<h1>HP Laptop Parts</h1>
<h2>Compatible with G62 CQ62 G56 CQ56 & MORE   </h2>

<a href="#" class="clickme">Keyboard housing Top Cover </a>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://hp-parts.orgfree.com/images/Housing/DSC_0308.jpg">

</div>

<a href="#" class="clickme">Touchpad Buttons Board , Cable & Frame</a>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://hp-parts.orgfree.com/images/Keypad%20Buttons/DSC_0280.jpg">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I changed code as bellow.**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://hp-parts.orgfree.com/hpcss.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
</head>

<body align="center">
<h1>HP Laptop Parts</h1>
<h2>Compatible with G62 CQ62 G56 CQ56 & MORE   </h2>

<a href="#" class="clickme">Keyboard housing Top Cover </a>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://hp-parts.orgfree.com/images/Housing/DSC_0308.jpg">

</div>

<a href="#" class="clickme">Touchpad Buttons Board , Cable & Frame</a>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://hp-parts.orgfree.com/images/Keypad%20Buttons/DSC_0280.jpg">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**myjs.js File**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
$('.box').hide();

// Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
// with a click event to toggle the "box" state
$('.clickme').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
        // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
        $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
})
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Is path of JS file correct?

Comment: Assuming the path to the js file is correct, what you have should work fine. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: According to this setup, the js file needs to be in the same directory as your html code for it to work.

Comment: when use first working code all photos are hidden when it loads 1st time... but second time all photos are visible at 1st page load

Comment: Path to the JS file is correct.. index.html and myjs.js file are in same folder...

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a doctype (html 5 doctype)..

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp

..you don't need to give a type for script tag.

Also you need to get to the base of your path by using **/**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://hp-parts.orgfree.com/hpcss.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/myjs.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also your script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Hide all the elements in the DOM that have a class of "box"
    $('.box').hide();

    // Make sure all the elements with a class of "clickme" are visible and bound
    // with a click event to toggle the "box" state
    $('.clickme').each(function () {
        $(this).show(0).on('click', function (e) {
            // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
            e.preventDefault();

            // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
            $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Missing **;** at the end..

Comment: Also <body align="center"> is not valid